# Cookie “pma_lang_https” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “domain” because the scheme does not match firefox error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, firefox, console

This alert is given when I refresh the home screen.

 My host does not use ssl certificate.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See [https://web.dev/schemeful-samesite/#:~:text=%22Cookie%20cookie_name%20will%20be%20soon%20treated%20as%20cross-site%20cookie%20against%20http%3A//site.example/%20because%20the%20scheme%20does%20not%20match.%22](https://web.dev/schemeful-samesite/#:%7E:text=%22Cookie%20cookie_name%20will%20be%20soon%20treated%20as%20cross-site%20cookie%20against%20http%3A//site.example/%20because%20the%20scheme%20does%20not%20match.%22)

The warning means that `pma_lang_http` cookie won't be shared with http version of your website in future i.e. http://localhost

You should make sure that all requests go to same scheme(i.e. HTTPS only) to avoid this issue.

Chrome seems to have already implemented this behaviour.

Comment: https in localhost !!

Comment: Yes. See this to know how you  can quickly get HTTPS for local web serverhttps://web.dev/how-to-use-local-https/#:~:text=Another%20option%20to%20access%20a%20locally%20running%20site%20with%20HTTPS%20is%20to%20use%20a%20reverse%20proxy%20such%20as%20ngrok.

Comment: Do you think this problem is due to https and these problems do not exist on the main host?

Comment: If the actual website is entirely on HTTPS then this problem won't exist there. e.g. if your website is myexample.com and all requests to the website are HTTPS only then there is no problem but if there are some requests to http://myexample.com and some to https://myexample.com it would be a problem